# Swift: Custom action for UIRefreshControl in WKWebView

Tags: swift, xcode, uirefreshcontrol

I'm using the newest `Xcode` and `Swift` version.

I'm using `WKWebView` to display content from my webserver.

I'm using the following code to `pull to refresh`:

```
let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refreshWebView(_:)), for: UIControl.Event.valueChanged)
homeWebView.scrollView.addSubview(refreshControl)
```

Since refreshing seems not to be the same as (re)loading an URL, this results to some unexpected behavior. Also, it doesn't trigger `func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didCommit navigation: WKNavigation!) {`.

Is there any way to `catch` the `pull to refresh` function and make some custom stuff e.g. loading another URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just change the action in `Selector` that you're passing to your custom action, here's how:

```
refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(myCustomAction), for: UIControl.Event.valueChanged)
```

Action:

```
@objc func myCustomAction() {
    print("my custom action here...")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4 and Swift 5**

```
lazy var refreshControl: UIRefreshControl = {
    let ref = UIRefreshControl()
    ref.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to refresh")
    ref.tintColor = UIColor.red
    ref.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refreshData), for: UIControl.Event.valueChanged)
    return ref
}()
```

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        myWebView.scrollView.addSubview(refreshControl) 
    }
```

```
@objc func refreshData(){
    //TODO:- Do whatever you want 
}
```